# Why should I use HiddenField?

Tags: asp.net

I don't see any reason why should I have a control I can't see it.

Here's a code I found on [tutorial for ASP.Net](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/ASP.NET/0060__ASP.net-Controls/WorkingwiththeHiddenFieldservercontrolC.htm) and I can't understand the usage

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>HiddenField Server Control</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
       <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Runat="Server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When should I use it?

Comment: It's a control which can store a value that you could also access on clientside with javascript to read or write and that the user can't see. Isn't this enough?

Comment: ViewState is a popular hidden field in ASP.NET web form.  that keeps track of state of web control on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Because it can be used on both the client and server; it's a great way to persist state of client-side components and a way to push data changed on the client to the server to persist.  A lot of AJAX controls (like AJAXControlToolkit) use hidden fields for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

A hidden field can be used to store and submit machine generated data that is required by the server, but would be meaningless and confusing to the user. One example of this could be an internal ID for a business entity.

Another good example is to store the Anti Forgery Token that is generated by the server to protect a web application against [Cross Site Request Forgery](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)).

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-(csrf)-attacks

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470175(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden fields to store value during the postback process on the same page.  Its work like viewstate. 
Its usefull to store value and use by JavaScript and server site code.